# R - Analyzing Relationship Between Two (or more) Binary Variables

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, binary-data

Say I have two vectors:

```
Action.Taken = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0)
Success = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
```

The first tells me whether or not a specific action was taken in a trial and the second tells me whether or not that trial succeeded. How would I go analyzing these two vectors to answer the following question: Does taking action (`Action.Taken = 1`) affect whether or not success is had (`Success = 1`)? I'd like some measure of significance as an regression/hypothesis testing.

I'm looking for an answer that I can implement using R. I am also quite new to stats, so it would be nice if someone could give me a relatively simple, straightforward answer/example.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the chi-square test for independence.

Comment: And the correlation coefficient (phi) that can be computed based on Chi-Square.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually tried the `prop.test` function, which returns, among other things, the p-value given the null hypothesis that two (or more) proportions aren't different. I think phi is just as simple as `cor(dat)`, but I don't know what/how much that tells me.

Answer (score 2):

As TrynnaDoStat says, I'd suggest using the chi-square test for independence. Start with:

```
contingency = table(Action.Taken, Success)
```

This gives you a contingency table, which displays the number of times you have action {1, 0} and success {1,0}. That can tell you whether success is more frequent when some action is taken. Then use:

```
chisq.test(contingency)
```

The p-value here tests the null that action taken is independent of success. If the p-value is greater than 0.05 you cannot reject the hypothesis that the two are independent at the 5% significance level. In other words, it doesn't matter what action you take - statistically it seems success is equally likely either way (at the 5% level).